# Navigation title not showing up in ResearchKit

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

How do you display the title of a TaskViewController in Research Kit? I've been trying the following and it doesn't seem to be showing up, although other properties can be set in this way.

```
    let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: ConsentTask, taskRunUUID: nil)
    taskViewController.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "TITLE"
    taskViewController.restorationIdentifier = "1"
    taskViewController.delegate = self
    presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have also tried taskViewController.title = "TITLE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform two steps:

1) Turn off the progress title:

```
taskViewController.showsProgressInNavigationBar = NO;
```

2) Implement and set a `delegate` for `ORKTaskViewController`:

```
- (void)taskViewController:(ORKTaskViewController *)taskViewController stepViewControllerWillAppear:(ORKStepViewController *)stepViewController {
    stepViewController.title = @"Your title";
}
```